# Как вычислить наибольшее число кратное 2?

Tags: python, range, max

```
a = range(0, 1000000)
if a % 2 == 0:
    a = d
    print(max(d))
```

Comment: print(999998) должно сработать

Comment: 2 * бесконечность.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Если прямо вот так в лоб, не анализируя, что за последовательность на входе, то вот так:

```
print(max(a for a in range(0,1000000) if a%2 == 0))
```

Функции `max` нужно передать последовательность, из которой она выберет максимальный элемент.

По хорошему то, конечно, нужно идти с конца, и вообще можно сделать гораздо проще в данном случае, просто отняв остаток от деления на 2 от верхней границы диапазона:

```
n = 1_000_000 - 1
print(n - n % 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, сработает, если создать цикл по убыванию и проверять каждое число на кратность двум

```
for i in range(1000000-1, 0, -1):
    if i%2 == 0:
        print(i)
        break
```

Comment: И сразу `break` после `print`

Comment: и if не нужен, сразу break ))

Comment: @Jack_oS `break` нужен, поскольку первая итерация нечётная )  Но можно и вообще без цикла так то

Comment: @Jack_oS, for не нужен. )

Answer (score 3):

```
a = range(0, N)
print(next(reversed(a))//2*2)
```

`reversed` от `range` не вычисляет все значения, а грубо говоря переставляет местами параметры `range`, поэтому даже для больших N считает мгновенно:

```
In [1]: N = 10**100                                                             

In [2]: a = range(0, N)                                                         

In [3]: %timeit next(iter(a))                                                   
134 ns ± 0.164 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit next(reversed(a))                                               
278 ns ± 0.226 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
n = int(input())
max_even = n-1 if n%2 else n

print(max_even)
```

вывод `max_even`:

```
>? 13
12

>? 42
42
```